# How to do hash1 or hash256 use ESB Tooling in Eclipse?

Tags: hash, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I have to build API use ESB Tooling in Eclipse, and I have to do hash1 and hash256 some variable.
How to do that?

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a standard mediator that does this but you might be able to use your own Java code that uses the required hashing libraries and call it via the [Class mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/Class+Mediator)